# Best way to cite collaborators that are unaffiliated with an academic institution or business?

Tags: journals, independent-researcher, affiliation

I am the lead author on a journal paper to the IEEE, and I'm trying to figure out how to cite other contributors in a way that makes sense.  Two of us are affiliated with a university, one contributor is a wonderful and knowledgable mathematician whose "real job" is in the service industry, and the other contributor is also a math nerd who is a barista in another country that did all of the proofs.

Would these non-conventional authors be "independent" or "unaffiliated" or some other term.  The affiliation is required by the journal.  Any suggestions (or a definitive source) of how to handle this issue would be appreciated.

Comment: In what sense is affiliation "required" by the journal?  A formal rule, or just a web form that can't be left blank?  In the former case, ask the journal what they want you to do.  In the latter, enter "none".

Comment: By the way, the word "cite" is not applicable here; that would be about referring to other papers by those people.  I would talk about how to "list" these collaborators.

Comment: @NateEldredge Two things, firstly, the affiliation is required, but mostly, I'd like a to be sure that protocol is followed, which leads me to the second part:  I was hoping for an authoritative reference.  As per that link, "Independent Scholar" is promising; however, I am still unsure if there's an official method.  An aside, "independent scholar" as a literal phrase translates terribly into the other language one of the researchers (one doesn't speak english), so a official reference would dismiss doubt about nuance.

Comment: Ok.  I don't know of any universally authoritative / official term or protocol for such situations.  The journal might have standardized on some specific term, but you would have to ask them about that.

Comment: @NateEldredge After a few rounds with the editors, we did decide on "Independent Scholar".